# calculate exponential moving average in matrix with nan values

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, moving-average

suppose I have the following matrix

a =

76       NaN    122    NaN

78       NaN    123    NaN

84  NaN 124    54

77  NaN 126    58

82  45  129    62

90  50  135    45

76  63  133    66

79  52  122    49

88  56  140    24

Is there any way to calculate exponential moving average for each column, disregarding the first NaN values? For instance, if I use a 3 days exponential factor, I would expect to get a matrix starting with 2 NaN values in the 1st column, 6 NaN values in the 2nd column,2 NaN values in the 3rd column and 4 NaN values in the 4th column. Any suggestion? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use filter on the whole matrix, which will pass through the NaN's as appropriate.  If you want to "infect" edge values with NaN as well, add some extras at the top edge, then trim the result:

```
kernel = [1 1 1].';   % Any 3-element kernel, as column vector
a2 = [repmat(NaN, 2, 4); a];  % Add extra NaN's at the start, to avoid partial answers
xtemp = filter(kernel, 1, a2);
x = xtemp(3:end, :);
```

Comment: thanks!, I follow your answer, i get the Nans where I want them to be, but the final matrix returns sums of values of a. Is there a way I can calculate exponential moving average instead?

Comment: I just used a sample filter kernel of values [1 1 1], which adds values.  I intend that you replace that kernel with whatever 3-element filter kernel you want.  I'm not sure how you define exponential moving average, so I didn't write out a kernel for you.